# Access a class's fields and methods with Java reflection

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a document class that has id, name, text and list of words. I try to compare id which I have with the ids and when found get the list of words attached to this id to find exact word. I was trying with java reflection but I'm unable to get it working?
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
public class Doc {
    private static int documentID;
    private static Doc docInstance = null;
    private String documentText;
    private ArrayList<String> listOfTokens;
    static int docCount = 0;

    public Doc() {
        documentID = 0;
        listOfTokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        tokFreq = 0;
        docCount++;
    }

    public static Doc getDocInstance() { 
        if (docInstance == null) {
            docInstance = new Doc();
        }
        return docInstance;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListOfTokens() { 
        return listOfTokens;
    }
}
```

and I am trying this

```
public static void createDocumentVector(TreeMap<Integer,Integer> 
documentVector, TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>qm, int N) throws 
NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, 
IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException, 
InvocationTargetException 
{
    int eachDoc = 0;

    Collection<String> allKeys = qm.keySet();
    ArrayList<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean addedTerm = false;

    /**
    Obtain an Iterator for Collection
    */
    Iterator<String> itr = allKeys.iterator();
    String key;
    int termFrequency = 0;
    int documentFrequency = 0;

    /**
     Iterate through TreeMap values iterator
     */
    while(itr.hasNext()) 
    {
        key = (String)itr.next();
        Integer LL = 0;
        l1 = qm.get(key); // Returns value of that key
        for (int k = 0; k < l1.size(); k++) 
        {
            LL = l2.get(k);

            Doc obj = new Doc();
            Class<? extends Doc> docOb = obj.getClass();
            Field field1 = docOb.getDeclaredField("documentID");
            field1.setAccessible(true);
            Field field2 = docOb.getDeclaredField("listOfTokens");
            field1.setAccessible(true);

            if (field1.isAccessible()) {
                Method setID = docOb.getDeclaredMethod("setDocumentID", new Class[]{int.class});
                setID.setAccessible(true);
                setID.invoke(docOb, LL);
            }

            Method listTock = docOb.getMethod("getListOfTokens");
            ArrayList<String> per = (ArrayList<String>) listTock.invoke(docOb, null);
            for (String tock : per) {
                if(tock.equals(key)) {
                    termFrequency++;
                }
            }

            documentFrequency = l1.size();
            eachDoc.add(getTFIDF(termFrequency, documentFrequency, N));
            documentVector.put(eachDoc, LL);
            addedTerm = true;
        }


    }
}
```

And I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Reflection is not supposed to be used to achieve your everyday programming. It is a nice, and sometimes helpful feature, but it is very expensive, and sidesteps a lot of OOP design principles, like encapsulation. If you are able to, you really need to re-write the document class. You should not need reflection to do the logic in `createDocumentVector`.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to do `new Doc()`, since `Doc` follows the singleton pattern. You should only ever have 1 `Doc` instance, which is why there's a `getDocInstance()` method. There's also no reason to access `listOfTokens` using reflections, since there's already a public getter. Whoever wrote that class needs to rewrite it.